# Not able to achieve two way-binding using Formik in "React.js"

Tags: reactjs

> ```
> class FruitShop extends Component {
>     constructor(props) {
>         super(props)
>         this.state = {
>             jobDetailsList: [],
>             fruitTitle: (typeof this.props.location.state !== 'undefined') ? this.props.location.state.fruitTitle : '',
>         };
>         this.showFruitListDetails = this.showFruitListDetails.bind(this);
>     }
>     showFruitListDetails(fruitList) {
>         this.setState({
>             fruitDetailsList: fruitList,
>         });
>         let fruitTitleValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.fruitDetailsList)).fruitTitle;
>         this.setState({
>             fruitTitle: fruitTitleValue,
>         });
>     }
>
>     render() {
>         return (
>             <Formik
>                 initialValues={{
>                     fruitTitle: this.state.fruitTitle,
>                 }}
>
>                 render={({ errors, touched, isSubmitting, setFieldValue }) => (
>                     !isSubmitting ? (
>
>                         <Form>
>                             <div>
>                                 <CloneNewFruitPage showFruitListDetailsHandler={this.showFruitListDetails} />
>                             </div>
>                             <div className="form-group">
>                                 <label htmlFor="fruitTitle">Fruit Title</label>
>                                 <Field name="fruitTitle" type="text" />
>                             </div>
>                         </Form>) : (<PageSpinner />)
>                 )}
>             />
>         );
> ```

1. In above code I am getting values for fruitDetailsList from CloneNewFruitPage which is child component for page FruitShop bypassing method(showFruitListDetails) as prop to CloneNewFruitPage
2. I have saved fruitTitleValue in state using the setState method (for state variable fruitTitle)
3. Now I wanted to auto-populate value for input field of formik(fruitTitle) instantly as soon as state is saved
4. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case `initialValues` values changes on runtime, you can always add the property `enableReinitialize={true}` to the `Formik` component.

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean